# Upload image laravel 9 stored as .tmp file in database

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-9

this is my first time using Laravel 9 and I want to ask some Question.
So I try to upload image and save it to database, then I want to show the image in my view. But the problem is in phpmyadmin it only shows the location where the uploaded file is stored as .tmp. The image that I uploaded is with the file name that matches what I want in the folder public/image, but why in database the name changes become `D:\xampp\tmp\php5819.tmp`, can anyone help me please?

Here's my controller:

```
 public function create()
{
    $student = Student::all();
    return view('create', ['addstudent' => $student]);
}

public function save(Request $request)
{
    $newName = '';
    if ($request->file('image')) {
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $newName = $request->name . '-' . now()->timestamp . '.' . $extension;
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('image', $newName, 'public');
    }

    $request['image'] = $newName;
    $student = Student::create($request->all());

    if ($student) {

        session()->flash('success', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan');
        session()->flash('pesan', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan');
    }
    return redirect('/about');
    // dd($request->all());
}
```

This is my View that I want to display the image:

```
@extends('layouts.templates')
@section('title', 'Detail')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Student Detail</h1>
      <div class="my-3">
        <img src="{{asset('image'.$student->image)}}" alt="{{ $student->name}}">
      </div>
      <h3>Nama : {{$student->name}}</h3>
      <h3>Gender : 
      @if ($student->gender == 'P')
        Perempuan
      @else
        Laki - laki
      @endif</h3>
      <h3>NIM : {{$student->NIM}}</h3>
      <a href="/about">Back</a>  
    </div>
</div>


@endsection
```

This is my Form

```
@extends('layouts.templates')
@section('title', 'Add Student')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 m-auto">
            <h2 class="my-3">Form Add Student</h2>
            <form action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Nama </label>
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="Masukkan Nama" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                    <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">Pilih</option>
                        <option value="L">L</option>
                        <option value="P">P</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <label for="NIM">NIM</label>
                    <input name="NIM" type="text" class="form-control" id="NIM" placeholder="Masukkan NIM">
                </div>
                <label for="NIM">Image</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image"
                        aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 mb-5">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/about">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Here's the error
[In database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sksGP.png)

In laravel folder
[Image name in laravel folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdJt8.png)

Database column name
[Column name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxjk9.png)

Comment: Could you share the table coumn names

Comment: done i share di column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the filename from request which is temp filename instead of Laravel stored.

The method `storeAs()` will return the path Laravel stored, try below.

```php
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    if ($request->file('image')) {
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // $newName = $request->name . '-' . now()->timestamp . '.' . $extension; No need for this.
        $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('image', $newName, 'public'); // Catch the path Laravel stored.
    }

    $data['image'] = basename($path); // Suggest save filename.ext only, if you need origin path just remove basename function.
    $student = Student::create($data);

    if ($student) {

        session()->flash('success', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan');
        session()->flash('pesan', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan');
    }
    return redirect('/about');
    // dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but it still doesn't change, in the database the name is still .tmp

Comment: @namarahasia Can you try again? Not assign into $request.